# Binary List to String List - Erlang

Tags: erlang

How do I convert `[<<"a">>, <<"b">>, <<"c">>]` to `["a", "b", "c"]`?

Answer (score 9):

`[binary_to_list(X) || X <- [<<"a">>, <<"b">>, <<"c">>]].` or more elaborate

```
BinList = [<<"a">>, <<"b">>, <<"c">>],
NormalList = [binary_to_list(X) || X <- BinList],
NormalList.
```

Comment: Link to binary_to_list docu: http://erldocs.com/R15B/erts/erlang.html?i=3#binary_to_list/1.

Comment: Link serves a 404.  Presumably this is the current location http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#binary_to_list-1

Answer (score 5):

Or, using lists:map/2:

```
lists:map(fun erlang:binary_to_list/1, [<<"a">>, <<"b">>, <<"c">>]).
```

Answer (score 2):

you can do it like this:

```
A=[<<"a">>, <<"b">>, <<"c">>]
B=[binary_to_list(Item) || Item <- A]
```